# Does Fedora 16 do automatic system updates?

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I typically use KDE except when I have to do some things that are broken in KDE such as starting a new Eclipse workspace, due to some graphic components Eclipse uses upon that action that are present in GNOME and not in KDE.  So today I went into GNOME after several days to start a new Eclipse project and was surprised that the DE layout was different than before.  E.g. the apps are organized in a tree by category in the upper left corner and, unlike before, there is an open app bar at the bottom (which is awesome because the lack thereof was what got me to switch to KDE in the first place).

However, I never performed a system update on request.  Since GNOME obviously got changed, without me going to `yum` or any other system update tool, I suspect that the OS is configured to do system updates on its own.  However, I would still like to be notified of pending updates and be asked to authorize them.  How can I view the system update preferences/configuration and change them?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 16 has been retired (end of life) some month or so ago. There are no more updates for that version, current Fedora version is 18. You would have to update at least to Fedora 17, or preferably from there to Fedora 18.

Comment: i am aware.  but how do i explain the update?

Comment: The repositories are presumably still available, and the package management machinery updates when it sees updates...